# ctags and ruby modules in vim

Tags: ruby, vim, ctags

I'm using ripper tags (https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags) to generate ctags files for a ruby project.

My goals is, in vim, to be able to jump from a line such as:

```
::Api::Contracts::Creator.new(
```

To the relevant file which defines that module.

This configuration works fine if there is only one module called `Creator`. But in practice there will be many `Creator`s in different namespaces, e.g there will also be an `::Api::Users::Creator`.

The above configuration will just jump to the first definition of `Creator` rather than the specific `Creator` in question.

Is there anyway to configure ctags so that it will jump to the specific definition?

Comment: what command are you using to run ripper-tags? it seems to me that either you're not properly giving it all source files, or there's something wrong with ripper that you should take up with them on their github.

Comment: @eiko I'm running it with `ripper-tags -R --exclude=vendor --exclude=chef --extra=q` which generates tags for the submodules. So if I do a visual select of `Administration::Contracts::Index` and then Ctrl+] it will go to the correct entry. But by default Ctrl+] I think only uses the current word under the cursor, e.g. `Index` whereas ideally i'd like it to expand to use the whole module definition. Thinking about it that might need a custom command...

Answer (score 1):

ripper-tags needs to be run with the option

```
--extra=1
```

So that tags will be generated which include the full module paths. This still leaves the problem that ctrl+] uses the current word so using it on `Module::Class` will only search for `Class`.

But this isn't really a ctags issue so I'll open a separate question on how best to write a custom command in vim to do this.

Using visual select to select the full definition and then ctrl+] will go to the correct definition.